# C# & C++ MFC : Create a book page using folder file count and order

Tags: c#, windows, mfc

I want to develop a module that performs the paging function so that the pictures in an arbitrary folder can be viewed like an e-book.
I am trying to implement interfaces and functions using `C #` and `C++ MFC`.

**Interface :**

[image]

Total count of files is not fixed.

**Example :**

```
+Folder : images
|_  image_01.jpg  
|_  image_02.jpg  
|_  image_03.jpg  

Total page : 3 (If an image is created in the folder:"images", Total page will be 4.)   
Current page : 2 (image_02.jpg)
```

If I press `<<PREV`(`NEXT>>`), application displays `image_01.jpg`(`image_03.jpg`).

Unfortunately I have no idea.  How can I implement this?

**I could not describe the code because I could not find a solution on the internet. Please do not vote down and teach me how to do it.**

Thank you in advance.

If you solve any of the `C # Windows Form Application` and `C ++ MFC Application solutions`, I will definitely **vote up**.

I would greatly appreciate if you could post two solutions at the same time.

Comment: You can make your own function : **Total page** = `GetFileCount(DIR_PATH)`; `GetPrevImage(NAME_CURRENT_IMAGE)`; `GetNextImage(NAME_CURRENT_IMAGE);` Main point is **Order of files**.

Comment: MFC is for C++, not C#.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you very much. Please give me some codes. (`C# Windows Form Application` and `C++ MFC Application`).

Comment: Don't beg for low-quality content to not get voted for what it is: Low-quality content. This question should be down- and close-voted. Please read [ask] to learn, what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**C++ MFC Windows Application Implementation :**

**ProjectName :** **`CImagePreview`**

```
DWORD ev_page_current, ev_page_total;
WCHAR ev_current_file[MAX_PATH];

void CImagePreview::OnPressPrevButton()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    ev_page_total = GetTotalPages(IMAGE_PATH);
    WCHAR wszPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    GetPrevImagePathW(IMAGE_PATH, ev_current_file, wszPath);
    DisplayImages(wszPath);

    ev_page_current > 1 ? ev_page_current-- : ev_page_current = 1;
    SetPageNumber();
}

void CImagePreview::OnPressNextButton()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    ev_page_total = GetTotalPages(IMAGE_PATH);

    WCHAR wszPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    GetNextImagePathW(IMAGE_PATH, ev_current_file, wszPath);
    DisplayImages(wszPath);

    ev_page_current < ev_page_total ? ev_page_current++ : ev_page_current = ev_page_total;
    SetPageNumber();
}

DWORD CImagePreview::DisplayImage(_In_ WCHAR* wszFilepath)
{
    // You can display image with path.
    return 0;
}

DWORD CImagePreview::GetNextImagePathW(_In_ WCHAR* wszFolderpath, _In_ WCHAR* wszFilename, _Out_ WCHAR* wszFilepath)
{return GetImagePathW(wszFolderpath, wszFilename, wszFilepath, NEXT);}

DWORD CImagePreview::GetPrevImagePathW(_In_ WCHAR* wszFolderpath, _In_ WCHAR* wszFilename, _Out_ WCHAR* wszFilepath)
{return GetImagePathW(wszFolderpath, wszFilename, wszFilepath, PREV);}

DWORD CImagePreview::GetImagePathW(_In_ WCHAR* wszFolderpath, _In_ WCHAR* wszInputFilename,  _Out_ WCHAR* wszOutputFilepath, _In_ DWORD dwFlag)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA t = {0};
    HANDLE hFindFile = NULL;
    BOOL blBreak = FALSE;

    WCHAR wszFilename[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    WCHAR wszFindpath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    WCHAR* wszFindname = NULL;

    if (wszInputFilename)
    {
        if (NULL != wcsstr(wszInputFilename, L"\\"))
        {
            wszFindname = wcsrchr(wszInputFilename, L'\\');
            wszFindname++;
        }
    }

    // First set folder path.
    wcscpy_s(wszOutputFilepath, MAX_PATH, wszFolderpath);

    wcscpy_s(wszFindpath, MAX_PATH, wszFolderpath);
    wcscat_s(wszFindpath, MAX_PATH, L"*.jpg");

    hFindFile = FindFirstFileW(wszFindpath, &t); if (hFindFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){return GetLastError();}
    wcscpy_s(wszFilename, MAX_PATH, t.cFileName);

    if( hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        do 
        {
            if (t.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){}
            else
            {
                if (NULL != wszFindname && !wcsicmp(wszFindname, t.cFileName))
                {
                    if (PREV == dwFlag) break;
                    if (NEXT == dwFlag) {blBreak = TRUE; continue;}
                    if (0 == dwFlag){wcscpy_s(wszFilename, MAX_PATH, t.cFileName); break;}
                }

                if (blBreak) break;

                if(0 == wcslen(wszInputFilename)) {wcscpy_s(wszFilename, MAX_PATH, t.cFileName); break;}

                wcscpy_s(wszFilename, MAX_PATH, t.cFileName);
            }
        } while (FindNextFileW(hFindFile, &t));
    }
    if (blBreak && NEXT == dwFlag) wcscpy_s(wszFilename, MAX_PATH, t.cFileName);

    FindClose(hFindFile);
    wcscat_s(wszOutputFilepath, MAX_PATH, wszFilename);

    return GetLastError();
}

INT CImagePreview::GetTotalPages(_In_ WCHAR* wszFolderpath)
{
    INT nTotalPage = 0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA t = {0};
    HANDLE hFindFile = NULL;
    WCHAR wszFindpath[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    wcscpy_s(wszFindpath, MAX_PATH, wszFolderpath);
    wcscat_s(wszFindpath, MAX_PATH, L"*.jpg");

    hFindFile = FindFirstFileW(wszFindpath, &t); if (hFindFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){return GetLastError();}

    if( hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        do {
            if (t.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){}
            else{nTotalPage++;}
        } while (FindNextFileW(hFindFile, &t));
    }
    FindClose(hFindFile);

    return nTotalPage;
}

VOID CImagePreview::SetPageNumber(void)
{
    CString cstrPage;
    cstrPage.Format(_T("%d/%d"), ev_page_total, ev_page_current);
    m_edit_page.SetWindowTextW((LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)cstrPage);

    return VOID();
}
```

The order of files in **`DIR_PATH`** can help you.   Also I tested my answer and it is working well.  I just made a e-pic-previewer because of you.

I do not think you need any more `C #` related solutions. I think it is the same as `MFC` solution ... How about it?

Comment: How is the order of images determined?

Comment: @Bryant The order of images is determined by the file name.

Comment: Your code working well. Thank you. I would really appreciate it if you could edit the `C #` code.